# A word for not knowing an appropriate word

Tags: vocabulary

What is a word to represent a situation in which we feel short of word to be able to express what we want to or what we are feeling .

Comment: Nice use of self-reference there :) I see what you did there :)

Comment: It depends on *why* you are lacking language. Is it surprise, confusion, limited vocabulary, lack of an expression in your native tongue, a totally unique item or experience?

Comment: Retentive is closely related to the word, retain. what about unretentive.

Comment: The extreme form is anomic aphasia.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ***tongue-tied*** for want of anything better.

We don't in English have anything quite like the French ***bon mot***, unless we say 'the appropriate word', which is a bit of a mouthful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have a nice simple word for this!

There are a few common phrases for not being able to find the right word:

- "it's on the tip of my tongue": when the word or phrase may actually come
- "what can I only describe as ...": when you have given up finding the perfect word and just describe what you mean

There is also the word "wordless" or the phrase "words fail me", but these mean "silently" and "I am so upset I cannot really respond" respectively.

If seems a neologism may be required: "word-lost"? :)

Answer (score 1):

The clinical word for this is **Aphasia**.  It ranges from forgetting a word here or there to total language block.

> Aphasia (/əˈfeɪʒə/, /əˈfeɪziə/ or /eɪˈfeɪziə/; from Greek a- ("without") + phásis (φάσις, "speech")) is an acquired language disorder caused by damage to the brain.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia)[2] This class of language disorder ranges from having difficulty remembering words to losing the ability to speak, read, or write, but does not affect intelligence.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia) This also affects visual language such as sign language.[2]

[WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an appropriate word for this ...

---

In all seriousness, the phrase

> Words cannot express ...

is often used for these situations.

For example, words cannot express the sadness experienced by one who witnesses the death of a loved one.

There is a hint of a paradox in this, as the fact that the phrase is composed of words itself, and is being used to describe whatever it says is impossible to describe with words.

Answer (score 0):

[*Perplexed*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/perplexed), [*at a loss for words*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/at+a+loss+for+words).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a word that would cover all the situations in which one might not find an appropriate English word to use. Perhaps the questioner could use an appropriate phrase such as 'words are inadequate to describe my feelings'.
Other languages draw fine distinctions not available in English and vice versa. We also do not have an appropriate word for everything we experience.

Answer (score 0):

How about the simple "***[speechless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/speechless?searchDictCode=all)***"?

> Unable to speak, especially as the temporary result of shock or strong emotion

Answer (score -1):

verklempt — 
popularized by Mike Myers in his Saturday Night Live skits "Coffee Talk with Linda Richards" .

Comment: Would you care to explain what is meant by this word?